# jQuery each function returning "Converting circular structure to JSON" error, used with $.proxy

Tags: jquery, json, parsing, scope, each

I am attempting to parse a JSON string of the form below:

```
var jsonString = {"body": "{\n \"data\": [\n {\n \"name\": \"{name}\",\n \"id\": \"{id}\"\n },\n {\n \"name\": \"{name}\",\n \"id\": \"{id}\"\n },\n {\n \"name\": \"{name}\",\n \"id\": \"{uid}\"\n },\n {\n \"name\": \"{name}\",\n \"id\": \"{uid}\"\n }\n ],\n \"paging\": {\n \"next\": \"http://graph.facebook.com/{my_uid}/mutualfriends?user={uid_1}&access_token={access_token}&limit=5000&offset=5000&__after_id={last_id}\"\n }\n}"}
```

Using the jQuery $.each function. When I execute the code below it parses as expected:

```
$.each(JSON.parse(jsonString).data,function(index,value){
      alert(JSON.stringify(value))
})
```

How ever I need to broaden the scope of the call back function. When I attempt to implement this using the code below.

```
$.each(JSON.parse(jsonString).data,$.proxy(function(index,value){
      alert(JSON.stringify(value))
}),this)
```

I get the error

```
Converting circular structure to JSON
```

Any help?

Update:

To be more specific the source of what I'm trying to parse is coming from a rest call. If I apply JSON.stringify() to the response I get:

```
            [{"code":200,"headers":[{"name":"Access-Control-Allow-Origin","value":"*"},{"name":"Cache-Control","value":"private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"},{"name":"Connection","value":"close"},{"name":"Content-Type","value":"text/javascript; charset=UTF-8"},{"name":"ETag","value":"\"d81f912b1730cdfd1c180d5851d2d22a8c0774c3\""},{"name":"Expires","value":"Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"},{"name":"Pragma","value":"no-cache"}],"body":"{\n   \"data\": [\n      {\n         \"name\": \"{name}\",\n         \"id\": \"{ID}\"\n      }\n   ],\n   \"paging\": {\n      \"next\": \"{URL}\"\n   }\n}"}]
```

I am then trying to parse this using:
    $.each(JSON.parse(jsonString).data,$.proxy(function(index,value){
          alert(JSON.stringify(value))
    }),this)

And getting the error

```
Converting circular structure to JSON
```

If I take our the $.proxy it works

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have made an edit so it is now contained in a JSON object.

Comment: When I fix the parenthesis problem in your code, it works. You'd better start by reducing your code in a fiddle to see where is really your problem.

Comment: See [working code](http://jsbin.com/ovidam/1/edit).

Comment: Hi @dystroy, thanks for you're fiddle. However it is nor parsing the exact same object I am dealing with (see update). The object I'm working with is coming from a REST call and I'm able to see it with out putting through the JSON.stringify() function so I'm not sure how to represent it in a fiddle in the same for as I am getting it from the REST response. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was the product of an un caught syntax error. Instead of

```
$.each(JSON.parse(jsonString).data,$.proxy(function(index,value){ alert(JSON.stringify(value)) }),this)
```

I needed:

```
$.each(JSON.parse(jsonString).data,$.proxy(function(index,value){ alert(JSON.stringify(value)) },this))
```